# Comparar arquivos de um diretório com md5sum e shellscript

Tags: algoritmo-de-busca, bash, shell-script, md5

Bom dia!

Estou estudando shellscript e um exercício pede pra que seja feita uma varredura de arquivos no diretório atual e que sejam calculados os hashes md5. Além disso pede pra que, caso existam arquivos idênticos pela comparação dos hashes, que sejam impressos esses arquivos. O código que consegui fazer consegue o resultado, porém ele sai duplicado; não consigo remover um arquivo das próximas varreduras uma vez que ele já tenha sido plotado como igual a um outro. Detalhe: não pode usar redirecionamento para arquivos temporários.

```
#!/bin/bash

ifs=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'

echo "Verificando os hashes dos arquivos do diretório atual..."

for file1 in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | cut -d "/" -f2); do
  md51=$(md5sum $file1  | cut -d " " -f1)
  for file2 in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | cut -d "/" -f2 | grep -v "$file1"); do
    md52=$(md5sum $file2 | cut -d " " -f1)
    if [ "$md51" == "$md52" ]; then
      echo "Arquivos $file1 e $file2 são iguais."
    fi
  done
done
```

Gostaria de saber também se há uma maneira mais eficiente de se fazer essa tarefa.

Desde já grato pela ajuda!

Answer (score 1):

Cara, eu consegui fazer com o `awk`, vê se isso te ajuda:

```
md5sum * | awk '{if(length(te[$1]) == 1) print "O arquivo: " te[$1] " e " $2  " são iguais."; else te[$1] = $2 }'
```

Explicando:

- `md5sum *` irá calcular o hash de todos os arquivos no diretório atual.
- `if(length(te[$1]) == 1)` checa se o valor hash já foi atribuído ao array.
- `print "O arquivo: " te[$1] " e " $2  " são iguais."` caso já tenha sido atribuído antes ele exibe a mensagem na tela.
- `else te[$1] = $2` caso não tenha sido atribuído ao array, ele irá atribuir o nome do arquivo com a chave hash.

Você pode ver alguns exemplos do `awk` [aqui](https://www.scriptbrasil.com.br/forum/topic/129342-tutorial-awk/).